# How to avoid indented newline after HTML comment in VSCode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have a simple bothering problem.

So, after I write a comment in VSCode, the newline become indented.

I know we can simply just delete it. But, it is uncomfortable to do repetitive thing like that.

I hope you guys can help me to solve this simple problem.

And for additional information, I thought it happened to empty tag, but when I write `<br>`, it isn't indented.

Comment: Is it in all programming languages or any specific programming language?

Comment: show (in text, no images) what you typed and where the cursor ends

Comment: @Mehrwarz Thanks for the help, I have know the way to fix it. I only just need to click both "ctrl + enter" or "shift + enter", and I will not face this problem again. Btw, I had mention I am using HTML on my question.

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for the help, but I had fix it. You only need to click "ctrl + enter" or "shift + enter" to create newline. This is will also help you type faster in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

For people face the same problem, try to using "ctrl + enter" or "shift + enter". This shortcut will help you type faster when coding because you can create newline without have put your pointer at the end of line. The newline also will not be indented. But if you keep have the same problem after try this way, maybe you should check your VSCode extensions.

Please vote closed, so no other spam answer, thanks!